# How to display help icon on accordion main panel

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created an accordion that when I expand displays minus(-) and when I collapse it, it displays plus(+).

Now I want to add a help icon in the accordion main panel. Once I click the help icon it should display one pop-up (without expanding or collapsing the accordion after the click on the icon).

Is it possible to do? How? I'm using bootstrap and jQuery.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="parent_accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#parent_accordion" href="#collapseONE">
               Accordion main panel
            </a>

        </h4>
    </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
    <div id="collapseONE" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
             Welocme Here            
        </div><!--/.panel-body -->
    </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.panel -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `glyphicon` (i suggest `glyphicon-info-sign` for a help button, but it's your choice) to your accordion:

```
<span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" 
      data-toggle="popover" 
      title="Popover Header" 
      data-placement="left" 
      data-content="Some content inside the popover"></span>
```

and place it with the class `pull-right` on the right side.
Then you add `data-toggle="popover"` to use bootstrap popover, place it on the left side with `data-placement="left"` and fill it with content: `data-title` and `data-content`.

You have to activate the popover with this javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
</script>
```

Here is your full HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="parent_accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#parent_accordion" href="#collapseONE">
               Accordion main panel
            </a>
            <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-placement="left" data-content="Some content inside the popover"></span>
        </h4>
    </div><!--/.panel-heading -->
    <div id="collapseONE" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
             Welocme Here            
        </div><!--/.panel-body -->
    </div><!--/.panel-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.panel -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this html markup that renders the icon:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-help"></span>
```

Then this script shows the popup when icon is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hlp').on('click', function(){
            $('#dlg').dialog({autopen:true});
    });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mop6q6zw/

Comment: I think some explanations would help

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will take care of what you want. Note the Help span is outside the toggle.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="parent_accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <div>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-help pull-left" onclick="test()"></span>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#parent_accordion" href="#collapseONE">
                        Accordion main panel
                    </a>
                </div>

            </h4>
        </div>
        <!--/.panel-heading -->
        <div id="collapseONE" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Welocme Here
            </div>
            <!--/.panel-body -->
        </div>
        <!--/.panel-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel -->

</body>
<script>
    function test() {
        alert("Hello");
        return (false);
    }
</script>
```